# I want to retrive each entity from following data in flutter

Tags: flutter

I want to sort each entity from following data in flutter
    i.e enrollment_no,nationality,mother this data is coming from api 
        "personal":

```
"{\"enrollment_no\":\"1701\",
     \"nationality\":\"INDIAN\",
     \"driver_mobile\":\"-\",
     \"mother\":\"JAGRUTIBAHEN SHRIKANT SONI\",
     \"email\":\"SHRIKANT206@YAHOO.CO.IN\",
     \"student_photo\":\"/container/school_data/BRS/photo/Student/1701.jpg\",
     \"name\":\"NEYSA SHRIKANT SONI\",
     \"mother_mobile\":\"+971507603564\",
     \"father_mobile\":\"+971503171294\",
     \"father\":\"SHRIKANT INDUKANT SONI\"}",
```

//I trying following code to sort data but can't achieve

```
     if(personal == data['personal']) {
     for (int i = 0; i < data['personal'].length; i++) 
       {
            arrayp = personal;
             print(arrayp);
            var array1=arrayp[0]['father'];
              print(array1);
       }
    }
```

Comment: see this https://flutter.dev/docs/cookbook/networking/background-parsing

Answer (score 0):

**1. Your JSON from API**

```
{
    "personal":  
        {
            "enrollment_no": "1701",
            "nationality": "INDIAN",
            "driver_mobile": "-",
            "mother": "JAGRUTIBAHEN SHRIKANT SONI",
            "email": "SHRIKANT206@YAHOO.CO.IN",
            "student_photo": "/container/school_data/BRS/photo/Student/1701.jpg",
            "name": "NEYSA SHRIKANT SONI",
            "mother_mobile": "+971507603564",
            "father_mobile": "+971503171294",
            "father": "SHRIKANT INDUKANT SONI"
        } 
}
```

**2. Go To https://javiercbk.github.io/json_to_dart/**

Convert your Json to Dart Classes.

```
class Personal {
  PersonalData personal;

    Personal({this.personal});

    factory Personal.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
        return Personal(
            personal: json['personal'] != null ?
            PersonalData.fromJson(json['personal']) : null, 
        );
    }

    Map<String, dynamic> toJson() {
        final Map<String, dynamic> data = new Map<String, dynamic>();
        if (this.personal != null) {
            data['personal'] = this.personal.toJson();
        }
        return data;
    }
}

class PersonalData {
    String driver_mobile;
    String email;
    String enrollment_no;
    String father;
    String father_mobile;
    String mother;
    String mother_mobile;
    String name;
    String nationality;
    String student_photo;

    PersonalData({this.driver_mobile, this.email, this.enrollment_no, this.father, this.father_mobile, this.mother, this.mother_mobile, this.name, this.nationality, this.student_photo});

    factory PersonalData.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
        return PersonalData(
            driver_mobile: json['driver_mobile'], 
            email: json['email'], 
            enrollment_no: json['enrollment_no'], 
            father: json['father'], 
            father_mobile: json['father_mobile'], 
            mother: json['mother'], 
            mother_mobile: json['mother_mobile'], 
            name: json['name'], 
            nationality: json['nationality'], 
            student_photo: json['student_photo'], 
        );
    }

    Map<String, dynamic> toJson() {
        final Map<String, dynamic> data = new Map<String, dynamic>();
        data['driver_mobile'] = this.driver_mobile;
        data['email'] = this.email;
        data['enrollment_no'] = this.enrollment_no;
        data['father'] = this.father;
        data['father_mobile'] = this.father_mobile;
        data['mother'] = this.mother;
        data['mother_mobile'] = this.mother_mobile;
        data['name'] = this.name;
        data['nationality'] = this.nationality;
        data['student_photo'] = this.student_photo;
        return data;
    }
}
```

**3. Now time for you api response**

```
_getResponseFromApi() asyn{

var response = await http.post({your parameters})

var data = Personal.fromJson(json.decode(response.body));

var listOfPersonData = data.personal

}
```

Comment: can you send complete json response?

Comment: check my updated answer @Rekha Choudhari. I have changed Model Class because you have Json Object of "personal" not list

Comment: Just Copy model classes again.

Comment: welcome ;), Hi @Rekha Choudhari, may you upvote my answer?